# Markdown does not allow for bold italic, then bold, then bold italic

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown

I am trying in one of my posts to do this:

```
***how many*** **and** ***where***
```

Which for some reason comes out like this:

[image: ***how many*** **and** ***where***]

Why is that happening?

Shouldn't the middle word be bold?

Is this [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) for markdown or is it (as I assume) a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)?

Comment: "I am trying in one of my posts to do this". I pity the site you're posting on

Comment: @TimStone Hmm. Why does an extra space work?

Comment: @TimStone well for one thing, I did not know I **could** do that (your second option).

Comment: Why not simply mix and match the asterisks and underscores?

Comment: @Lix I tried that, It doesn't work, the same thing happens.

Comment: Why not simply refrain from doing this at all?

Comment: Daring Fireball's perl implementation produces the expected result, so this is a bug.  How urgent a bug is up for debate :)

Comment: What a ridiculous reaction from the community, honestly. "Just don't do it"? "Pity the site you're posting on"? Imagine if your word processor didn't allow you to mix bold and italics like this, and its developer just told you "Are you seriously trying to use such formatting in your document? Just don't!"

Comment: It's not really "the community", though, just Michael Mrozek wasting everyone's time with the statement he made.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The obvious answer is to just *not do that*, but if you're that intent on it, try one of the following ways:

```
***bold italic* bold *bold italic***
```

***bold italic* bold *bold italic***

```
***bold italic***  **bold** ***bold italic***
```

***bold italic***  **bold** ***bold italic***

```
**_bold italic_ bold _bold italic_** // for the "prettier" HTML
```

***bold italic* bold *bold italic***

To satiate [Michael Mrozek's curiosity](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126382/markdown-does-not-allow-for-bold-italic-then-bold-then-bold-italic#comment342269_126382), the extra space works because the strict bold-italic parser needs a space (or other non-word character) to match, and the first bold italic group gobbles the single space you had there originally, depriving the bold group of it. As a result only the italics group that's a subset of the bold group (that is, the `*and*` within the `**and**`) matches.

Comment: As a side note, the actual processing works a little differently in each case, but I'm not sure if anyone cares about it to that extent.

Comment: The first one makes more sense. It's almost like... simplifying programming logic. :o No way!

Comment: @animuson The last one produces the nicest HTML though, I suppose.

Answer (score 8):

***bold italic***  **bold** ***bold italic***

```
***bold italic***  **bold** ***bold italic***
```

Notice the extra space between the 1st `bold italic` and the `bold` sections.

Comment: Ahh but that is **not** what I want. sorry the title did not match the OP. read the OP! :-P

Comment: @ChrisF -- why should I need to make the **extra** space?

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA - no idea, but it works :)

Comment: @ChrisF So basically my way is bydesign?

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA - No idea.

Comment: @ChrisF odd. hmm

Answer (score 8):

This is fixed in the next build.

Server: https://code.google.com/p/markdownsharp/source/detail?r=6f4eabfa291169c1c0969d80a20eb6c2f202e35d

Client: https://code.google.com/p/pagedown/source/detail?r=ec83ecf78c0c01ab8725c0b9614b9af6c4f6ecf5