# Bold text conversion doesn't work across paragraph break

Tags: support, design, markdown

When there is a paragraph break between two bold codes (double asterisk), the asterisks are displayed and nothing is bolded.  Is it a bug, or intentional?

Possibly related; not duplicate: [Markdown does not allow for bold italic, then bold, then bold italic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126382/markdown-does-not-allow-for-bold-italic-then-bold-then-bold-italic)

**Example one

Example two**

(If the break exists before clicking for bold, the blank line is removed and both lines are bold.  If the break is entered after bolding, it renders as shown currently.

Comment: You're talking about this? https://imgur.com/a/8WzSjUc

Comment: You ask whether my post is asking about an image of my post?

Comment: I'm asking if the editing that the image shows is what you say you can't do?(Line breaks between `**`.....`**`). Have a look at the edit and compare it to the result of the edit (which is in the same image).

Comment: No, that shows a single paragraph bolded.  I did not say "line break," I said "paragraph break."

Comment: Adding an example *would* make your question clearer, and less likely to mis-interpreted.

Comment: I'm adding an example, even though the question has already been answered.

Comment: @WGroleau. Sorry, it was a misinterpretation on my part.

Comment: No hay de que.  Lo he mejorado.

Comment: Yo no hablo Español.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That is by design.

In [Blocks and inlines](https://spec.commonmark.org/0.31.2/#precedence) it is defined that *Indicators of block structure always take precedence over indicators of inline structure.*

A paragraph is a block structure.

The chapter [Emphasis and strong emphasis](https://spec.commonmark.org/0.31.2/#emphasis-and-strong-emphasis) defines, as part of inline structures, how emphasis start and end. As such those never escape the block they are in.

Emphasis needs to be dealt with inside each paragraph. With markdown you can't achieve a bold HTML end result spanning two paragraphs.

That said: You can leave it to your browser to render something reasonable out of HTML soup.

**Bold text**

to next paragraph

Html you need for above effect:

```html
<p>
  <b>Bold text
</p>
<p>
  to next paragraph</b>
</p>
```

Tim Berners-Lee and I call that broken HTML and is better avoided.

---

**Footnote**

Some might claim that *the HTML in your rendered example isn't what is in your unrendered example* but that depends on what the browser makes of it when it parse the HTML into an actual DOM.

This is the raw network response:

[image]

and Chrome did it best to make something useful out of it:

[image]

Now try that with IE6!

Comment: Broken, I agree.  Also agree it's "better avoided" if writing raw HTML, but people using markdown aren't doing that.  I didn't stop to inspect the raw HTML when it happened.

Comment: I see that the HTML in your rendered example isn't what is in your unrendered (broken) example.

Comment: So, Chrome and Safari (mine) actually changed the HTML they received.  Both had an unnecessary insert between the "real" paragraphs.  Safari's was an empty (no space) bold with paragraph tags around it.

Comment: @WGroleau I think the main problem is a lack of an RFC that specifies how non-conformant HTML needs to be projected into a Document Object Model. Before HTML 5 we had an attempt at XHTML with one of its design goals to get rid of ambiguity in both  format and processing. That breaking change never made it passed the big browser vendors, leading to our current state where handling non-conformant html is an implementation detail for each browser. It is better to not rely on that detail as it might change in the next version of your favorite browser.

Comment: "So, Chrome and Safari (mine) actually changed the HTML they received." - no; they **created a DOM** from the HTML they received, with a [liberal interpretation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robustness_principle), then used conservatively (pedantically) crafted HTML to represent that DOM back to you.